# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and WSO2 Application Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI, because i did not find DataSource Menu from sidebar of WSO2 ESB ...

WSO2 AS has feature that deploys .war and other web app files.

- Does WSO2 EI have kind of this Feature ?
- Some WSO2 products are different feature than others. How to install features on WSO2 ESB

Thanks.

Comment: Installing features https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/30542404  though  you should check which feature version is compatible with which carbon / product version

Comment: What is the difference wso2 developer studio and integration studio ?
for develop WSO2 ESB integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2 EI the Datasources menu in the configure tab as below,

[image]

It is possible to install features in WSO2 ESB. You can follow [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Working+with+Features#WorkingwithFeatures-Installingfeaturesfromthemanagementconsole) to get it done via management console and [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Working+with+Features#WorkingwithFeatures-pom_approachInstallingfeaturesusingpomfiles) to do it via pom files. But it is not recommended to install features on standard products, as it can create complexities when it comes to use [wum](https://docs.wso2.com/display/updates/Getting+Started), etc.

Answer (score 0):

1: Does WSO2 EI have kind of this Feature ?

A: You can't deploy .war or .jar file on wso2 EI.
You can deploy only .car file on web portal.

2.Some WSO2 products are different feature than others. How to install features on WSO2 ESB?

A: it's not posible to install the feature of WSO2 other feature on other.
EX: if you use EI portal and you want the features of Api Manager to install on EI, it's not possible.

Comment: You are right but I mentioned about WSO2 AS has a feature that deploys .war and other web app files.